# openpyxl writing in a cell and copying previous format doesn't work: format is not applied

Tags: python, excel

To preserve the background colour and the font colour when updating a cell value with `openpyxl`, I tried to store the original background colour and font colour to then re-apply it after modifying the value since setting a value would remove the formatting. However, it does not work and I'm not sure I understand why.

To reproduce the issue, you need a `example.xlsx` file. You can either download it (https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f3accf7902a97bd18fb12bb08064419720230419122708/397f42) or create the file yourself in case the link expired or in case you wouldn't want to download something from a random on the internet. To create the file, I highlighted columns `B`, `C`, `D` in yellow and set the font to red. Then I wrote test in the cells `B1`, `C1` and `D1`.

I'm trying to write `Hello World` in the cell `B2` without losing the yellow background colour and the red font.

MRE:

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')  # download the example.xlsx file at https://wetransfer.com/downloads/72662284d9231c96e82f65a054c262ea20230410215338/d7c23b
ws = wb.active

cell = ws.cell(row=2, column=2)
original_fill = cell.fill
original_font = cell.font

cell.value = 'Hello World'

new_fill = PatternFill(fill_type=original_fill.fill_type,
                       start_color=original_fill.start_color,
                       end_color=original_fill.end_color,
                       fgColor=original_fill.fgColor,
                       bgColor=original_fill.bgColor)
cell.fill = new_fill

new_font = Font(name=original_font.name, size=original_font.size, bold=original_font.bold, italic=original_font.italic,
                vertAlign=original_font.vertAlign, underline=original_font.underline, strike=original_font.strike,
                color=original_font.color)
cell.font = new_font

wb.save('example_result.xlsx')
```

I'm using `openpyxl==3.1.2` and `Python 3.11.1`.

I've read somewhere that this was one of the many shortcomings of `openpyxl`, if this is the case and I can't go around that issue, what library would you suggest? I would like something that isn't too long.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution requires pre-defining the font color and the background color**

I hope this helps you reach the solution faster.

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font

red_font = "FF0000"
yellow_bg = "FFFF00"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')

ws= wb['Sheet1']

cell = ws.cell(row=2, column=2)

original_fill = cell.fill
original_font = cell.font

cell.value = 'Hello world'

font = Font(name=original_font.name, size=original_font.sz, color=red_font, bold=original_font.b, 
                            italic=original_font.i, underline='none')
fill = PatternFill(start_color=yellow_bg, end_color=yellow_bg, fill_type='solid') 

cell.font = font
cell.fill = fill

wb.save('result_example.xlsx')
```

Comment: I believe this works and my solution doesn't work because when I do `original_fill = cell.fill`, `openpyxl` doesn't actually grab anything (row number 2 not being defined "yet"). Good to know! but quite annoying in cases you don't know beforehands the colour you want.